# How to auto extracting nested json in which few json object nested json object but can be parsed with __dict__

Tags: python, json, nested

object looks like as below

```
{
"id":1,
"image":"path/to/image",
"employee_data":<sql_alcahmy_object>,
}
```

again sql_alcahmy_object is as below

```
{
"employee_previous":<sql_alchemy_object2>,
"employee_salary":"1$",

}
```

again sql_alcahmy_object2 is as below

```
{"company":"xyz","years":10}
```

below method will be used to extract all data from sql alchemy object

```py
sql_alchemy_object.__dict__
```

below is the recursive method planned but it didn't work out

```py
def extract_recursive(deepvalue,alldata={}):
    for eachkey,eachvalue in deepvalue.__dict__.iteritems():
        if hasattr(eachvalue,"__dict__"):
            alldata.update({eachkey:extract_recursive(eachvalue)})
        else:   
            alldata.update({eachkey:eachvalue})
    print(alldata)
```

expected output

```
{
"id":1,
"image":"path/to/image",
"employee_data":{
             "employee_previous":{"company":"xyz","years":10},
             "employee_salary":"1$",

              }
}
```

Available methods in deepvalue and sql_alcahmy_object as below

```py
 ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__mapper__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__table__', '__tablename__', '__weakref__', '_decl_class_registry', '_sa_class_manager', 'age']
```

Comment: There isn't a question anywhere here, just a series of statements. What exactly are you asking? What are the issues you face?

Answer (score 0):

There is a misunderstanding of what is [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__dict__#object.__dict__) here

It actually is

> A dictionary or other mapping object used to store an object’s (writable) attributes.

but it does not allow to access nested dicts of a dict.

So, if you want to iterate over items in a dict, you just have to call `thedict.iteritems()` not `thedict.__dict__.iteritems()`.

Then, if you want to check if variable contains a `dict` instance, use `isinstance(a_dict, dict)`, not `hasattr(a_dict, '__dict__')`.

Additionaly, using a mutable object as a default value for a function argument can produce non-intuitive result and is strongly discouraged (see ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument))
Instead you should probably pass `None` as default value and add a `alldata = alldata or {}` at the begining of your function.

Finally, although I do not understand the point of your function, this version should work better:

```
def extract_recursive(deepvalue, alldata=None):
    alldata = alldata or {}
    for eachkey, eachvalue in deepvalue.iteritems():
        if isinstance(eachvalue, dict):
            alldata.update({eachkey:extract_recursive(eachvalue)})
        else:
            alldata.update({eachkey:eachvalue})
    print(alldata)
```

Comment: but issue here is I don't have deepvalue.iteritems(), I can only fetch it through deep value__dict__.iteritems()

Comment: @Harish: what is the type those "sql_alchemy_object"

Comment: its class object it  doesn't have iteritems  method and  model was written by others so I am not authorised to change

Comment: @Harish: It will be difficult to help without detail. What does return a `type(<the variable which contain the sql_alchemy_object>)`? If it is a standard type, we could potentially help you. It is a custom type and you cannot share the code, you still can inspect it with `dir(<the variable which contain the sql_alchemy_object>)` looking for a suitable attribute...